# egrep to find in a file with numbers and words those numbers not starting with 91 or 93

Tags: regex, grep, egrep

I have a file with numbers and words and I need to get only numbers:

File:

```
ASCII
Baron
Cbada
Dbadal
ebadals
Abadessa
Abadesses
Abadia
Abarca
jbarques
Zbat
Abdalong
Rbdies
Abdon
Abel
ibelard
Abell
Abella
Abellan
Abellana
quebellanes
370
410
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
87654321
7654321
654321
54321
4321
321
21
937895432
938965432
930895432
913769890
916767800
91676780
977895432
```

if I do `egrep "\b[^9][0-9]+"` I do not get the one starting with 97.

And obviously `"\b[^91][0-9]+"` don't show the ones starting with 9 or 1.

If I do `egrep -v "\b9[13]"` I get the words, which I don't want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<file egrep '^[0-9]+' | egrep -v '^9(1|3)'
```

or

```
egrep -v '^9(1|3)|[[:alpha:]]' file
```

> -v, --invert-match
>           Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.

Comment: I tried this solution, sorry I didn't mention it at the question, and with it I get also words, I need only numbers, I'll modify the question...

Comment: Maybe chain egreps?

Comment: @QuickishFM Yes, I guess that's the easiest solution.

Comment: @QuickishFM And what the chain would be?

Comment: First egrep for the numbers you need, including what you dont. Then, filter out from those with ^9(1|3) using a pipe. For example, `cat numbers.txt | egrep (first egrep for numbers) | egrep (second egrep for inversion)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, thanks to the comment of @QuickishFM I came up with this solution:

```
egrep -v "\b9[13]" file | egrep "[0-9]+"
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, `9[13]` is even shorter than `9(1|3)` and works with the grep without "e"!

Comment: No worries - The process of using _pipes_ to daisy chain the inputs to process them bit by bit is fairly common in Linux - for example, if you wanted to find the local IP address, you could run `ifconfig | grep 192.168 | cut -d " " -f 10` which runs ifconfig, then greps for the line with the IP, then delimits by spaces and selects the IP address. If you are new to Linux or Unix I suggest practising this - it may greatly help you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep -P` (`PCRE`) with a negative lookahead to make sure lines don't begin with `91` or `93`:

```
grep -P  '^(?!9[13])[0-9]+$' file
370
410
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
1234567
12345678
123456789
87654321
7654321
654321
54321
4321
321
21
977895432
```